# Is my current implementation of the residual blocks correct?

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, resnet

I have a question for you, I wrote what I think is a residual network architecture script using keras, yet I am not sure I managed to reproduce the residual blocks.

I would like to make sure that my script does reproduce the architecture. My python scripting skills are not optimum so I tried to make the residual blocks as I understood them. It is cumbersome yet straightforward I split them in 2 parts (very cumbersome so...); one which is the standard residual block called **res** something and one when downsampling which is called **red**. I then stacke them all. Of note, I am using preactivated blocks (so BN--> Relu --> Layer)

Here is a the part of the script that deals with the residual blocks;

```
def res1(Input):
    shortcut = Input
    layer0 = BatchNormalization()(Input)
    layer0 = Activation('relu')(layer0)
    layer0 = Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=(1,1), strides=(1,1), padding='same', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(weight_decay), kernel_initializer='he_normal')(layer0)
    layer0 = BatchNormalization()(layer0)
    layer0 = Activation('relu')(layer0)
    layer0 = Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1), padding='same', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(weight_decay),kernel_initializer='he_normal')(layer0)
    layer0 = BatchNormalization()(layer0)
    layer0 = Activation('relu')(layer0)
    layer0 = Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(1,1), strides=(1,1), padding='same', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(weight_decay), kernel_initializer='he_normal')(layer0)
    layer0 = add([layer0, shortcut])
    layer0 = Activation('relu')(layer0)
    return layer0

def red1(Input):
    shortcut = Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(1,1), strides=(2,2), padding='same', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(weight_decay), kernel_initializer='he_normal')(Input)
    shortcut = BatchNormalization()(shortcut)
    layer0 = BatchNormalization()(Input)
    layer0 = Activation('relu')(layer0)
    layer0 = Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1), padding='same', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(weight_decay), kernel_initializer='he_normal')(layer0)
    layer0 = BatchNormalization()(layer0)
    layer0 = Activation('relu')(layer0)
    layer0 = Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1), padding='same', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(weight_decay), kernel_initializer='he_normal')(layer0)
    layer0 = BatchNormalization()(layer0)
    layer0 = Activation('relu')(layer0)
    layer0 = Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(2,2), padding='same', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(weight_decay), kernel_initializer='he_normal')(layer0)
    layer0 = add([layer0, shortcut])
    layer0 = Activation('relu')(layer0)
    return layer0

input_shape = x_train.shape[1:]
input_img = Input(shape=input_shape)
x = conv1(input_img)
x = maxpool(x)
x = res1(x)
x = res1(x)
x = res1(x)
x = red1(x)
.
.
.
output = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(x)
```

The given information is very sparse but my **question is not about why does my architecture is bad ?**

It really is do you feel that the residual blocks have been implemented correctly (though not in the most efficient way I realize) ?

I am working on how to iterate over them a certain number of time but I would like to know whether there is something I misunderstood.

Best wishes all !

Comment: Why are redefining `layer0` again and again? That doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: How come ? I created 2 paths; (1) for the shortcut and another one (2) specifically in order to go through the preactivated layers. Edit; I believe that using a different name for each end every line would quickly get even more cumbersome than it already is.